# Salesforce1 button expose VF Page

Tags: salesforce1-app, chatter, visualforce, global-actions

I have a requirement to render a VF page in salesforce1 on Account Page when a button is clicked on a particular Account record. Please let me know how to achieve that. Searching in google can't get an effective suitable way.

Please find my VF page below.

## Please Wait

Redirecting ....
  
    if ( (typeof window.sforce != 'undefined') && (window.sforce!=null) ) {
      sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/searchAccts?id={!Account.id}');
    }
    else {
      alert('Not in SF1 :(');
    }

Answer (score 0):

I created a Visualforce Page, marked it as "Available for Salesforce Mobile" and related it to a custom button on the Account object.  When I view an account in SF1 It appears in the set of actions at the bottom of the page (when I select the ellipse)

[image: SF1 Menu]